# Strange change of variable's value

Tags: objective-c

I have this simple piece of code when I am logging variable's value:

```
    NSLog(@"set.nflag - %@", set.nflag1);
    if (set.nflag1 == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1])
    {
        NSLog(@"set.nflag - %@", set.nflag1);
        [sectionArray insertObject:_checkboxCell atIndex:set.nflag1];
    }
```

at last row I have crash an log is:

```
2013-09-26 11:36:12.537 PharmaTouch[1325:c07] set.nflag - 1  2013-09-26 11:36:12.537 PharmaTouch[1325:c07] set.nflag - 1  2013-09-26 11:36:12.538 PharmaTouch[1325:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 127347632 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

What can cause of changing value for

> set.nflag1

?

Comment: it is not clear why you think the value is changing

Comment: as we can see from log it is equal to 1 before if-, the same as inside if- and then it equal to 127347632

Comment: Try adding NSInteger index = [set.nflag1 intValue]; [sectionArray insertObject:_checkboxCell atIndex:index];

Answer (score 2):

The exception shows that sectionArray isn't allocated. Add this somewhere before this gets executed.

> sectionArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Try adding:

```
NSInteger index = [set.nflag1 intValue]; 
[sectionArray insertObject:_checkboxCell atIndex:index];
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is allocated and initialized right before if-statement

Comment: Ah another good guard to insert.  if ( array == nil ) { ...create new array ...} before adding anything to it.

Comment: Edited my answer for additional option.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the

```
set.nflag1
```

is of type NSNumber*. This is a pointer, not NSUInteger.
Do this:

```
[sectionArray insertObject:_checkboxCell atIndex:set.nflag1.unsignedIntegerValue];
```

Also, when comparing NSNumbers, use *isEqualToNumber:* method or just retrieve the int before the comparison.

Make sure you allocate the NSMutableArray before you try the insertion. Also, look out not to give it too big index

> Raises an NSRangeException if index is greater than the number of elements in the array.

Comment: also == should not be used to compare NSNumber

Answer (score 1):

1 is beyond the bounds of an empty 0 indexed array. 
Try adding a guard to check the array length before insertion. 
Or try simply adding it to the end of the array or 
Pad your array with instances of the NSNull singleton if you really need the NSNumber at the eponymous index.